# S4 method for `predict` dispatching on object and newdata classes

Tags: r, methods, r-s4

`predict` is defined with arguments `object` and `...`. I derived a PCA-like model which I call pcaadd and wrote a `predict.pcaadd` function. So far so good. Now I'd like to add an (S4) method that works for `object` with signature `"pcaadd"` and a particular kind of object in  `newdata` (signature `"hyperSpec"`).

(How) can I do this if the generic is defined with  `object` and `...` only?

Here's what I do for the moment: check the class of `newdata` and do the appropriate processing, but it seems not quite a clean solution:

```
predict.pcaadd <- function (object, newdata, ...){
  ## deal with class "hyperSpec"
  if (is (newdata, "hyperSpec")){
    validObject (newdata)

    ## extract the matrix that is used for the prediction
    newdata <- newdata [[]]
  }

  ## default part of prediction
  tmp <- predict (object$pca, newdata)
  tcrossprod (tmp [, - object$refcomps], object$pca$rotation [, -object$refcomps])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I used `as.matrix (object)` in the `predict` function which takes care of proper dispatch for different types of `newdata` (as it can be defined for any type of `newdata`).